# Why is my jQuery UI button not working when defined with a class selector but fine with id selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, jquery-selectors

I have two buttons in my document.

One is defined with an id selector in my jQuery code:

```
<button id="reviewBtn" class="span-1">Review</button>

$("#reviewBtn").button({
    icons: {primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-e"},
    text: false
});
```

The other is defined with a class selector:

```
<button id="search_364489867" class="span-1 searchBtn search">Search</button>

$("button.search").button({
    icons: {    secondary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-e"},
    text: true
});
```

The button defined with the class selector (`button.search`) is not being decorated with jQuery UI styles whereas the button defined with the id selector (`#reviewBtn`) appears as expected.

**Can I not define the button with the class selector?**

**If not, then how do I define it with a dynamically generated id value (`search_364489867`)?**

Comment: Are the buttons being added dynamically, after your code runs? Try putting `alert($("button.search").length)` and see what pops up.

Comment: Seems to work ok for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/sje397/72gBh/

Comment: I have the same problem. Selector is fine. Something with jqueryui is not.

Answer (score 0):

**When debugging most of the time you're checking your assumptions.**

So check your assumptions: instead of the call to .button() do a simpler method like,

```
$("button.search").slideUp(2000);
```

If the button does nothing, your selector is probably wrong.
If the button slides up you know your selector is right, but the method call is wrong or isn't working.

Then check your assumptions with the method call, etc